# Need help to optimize SQL select query with data functions

Tags: sql-server

I implemented a SQL query as mentioned below

```
SELECT OLT.status,
       OLT.queuedate,
       ( CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), OLT.queuedate, 101)
         + ' '
         + Stuff(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), OLT.queuedate, 109), 14), 9, 4, ' ')
       )
FROM   onlineresults OLT WITH(nolock)
       LEFT JOIN roadmap CR WITH(nolock)
              ON OLT.roadmapid = CR.content_roadmap_id
```

The OnlineResults is having only 1,43000 records, but it taking nearly 5 minutes to complete the above query..

do we have any other way to make the query faster by creating indexes

Schema of Onlineresults table

```
OnlineID (Primary Key)
RoadmapId
StudentId
SectionId
Status
Retries
QueueDate
```

There are many fields in roadmap table and content_roadmap_id is primary key

Comment: Bhuvan, can you use EXPLAIN ANALYZE and paste the result. Also please include the table definitions (if possible, or atleast the relevant fields).

Comment: @Vlad, i updated my question by appending the schema of the table.. what do you mean by Explain Analyze?  Is it is a Query Execution Plan in SQL Server

Comment: In SQL Server you can use Database Engine Tuning Advisor to identify missing indexes

Comment: Why do you left join with `roadmap`?

Comment: @adrianm because i need to display roadmapdate from the roadmap table

Comment: So you want readers to optimize another query than the one shown. Good luck

Comment: @adrianm , no i just removed the column from the select list to make query more readable for readers... its the same query..

Answer (score 0):

Yes indexes will effect the result.

You can do something like
1. Check both column have pk or index, if no , then create on it. Always use pk value to filter the data. Also try to filter data as much as possible when your query take too much.

2. On **queuedate** column give index with casting result which give faster result. OR create a new column whose value is **(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), OLT.QueueDate , 101)**

Add a calculated column to your table and create an index on this column.

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable
Add Column queuedateCalculated As (CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), OLT.QueueDate , 101)

Then create an index on this.

CREATE INDEX queuedateCalculatedIdx ON MyTable.queuedateCalculated
```

refer link
[SQL Server - index on a computed column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1323214/sql-server-index-on-a-computed-column)

Please check the execution plan for both condition.. here is good article to understand plan with indexes.

https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/jonathan/finding-what-queries-in-the-plan-cache-use-a-specific-index/

https://sqlserverfast.com/?s=user+defined+ugly

Or you can create a index view also .

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/199058/SQL-Server-Indexed-Views-Speed-Up-Your-Select-Quer

Comment: Instead of this can we create an indexed view? to resolve the issue