# Lazy loading in a bool

Tags: c#, lazy-loading

I have a code that has to go through every item on a database and then decrypt what they pull back.  I was told that lazy loading is a good way to go but I don't even know what it really is.  I read up on it but I am still unclear. Below is the code that brings every item I need.  How do I lazy load this so it doesn't bug down the system?

```
var potentialNumbers = _db.Owners.Where(x => x.UNQ4.Equals(submittedUNQ.Substring(submittedUNQ.Length - 4))).ToList().Select(o => o.UNQ).ToList();
```

Comment: Assuming `UNQ4` is a `string`, no Lazy-Loading is involved here. Lazy Loading is only applicable for navigation-properties (and when you actually access them, not when you query on them). See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574232(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: You need to post the code for your model too.

Comment: Start by removing all of the `ToList` calls that do nothing but inhibit what deferred execution is already happening, and force operations that *could* be performed by the DB to happen in your application.  You're literally going out of your way to do extra work that accomplishes nothing useful, and actively inhibits what you're trying to do.

Comment: You may also consider [limiting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2656576/select-top-5-in-entity-framework) the amount of rows to select if it is appropriate. Though the best performance improvement you can get can be achieved by something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1323214/sql-server-index-on-a-computed-column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lazy-loading in Entity Framework is turned on by default. You cannot force something to be 'lazily-loaded'. All you can do is turn off lazy-loading (which by the way, isn't actually eager-loading, it's 'no-loading'). So the answer is you can't. Indeed, however, as the comments have pointed out, if `Owners` class has a navigation property like, for instance,

```
public class Owners{
    public string UNQ4 {get;set;}
    public virtual OtherClass NavigationProperty {get;set;}
}
```

Then the `NavigationProperty` property will have a value of `null` initially when you do a query such as `var owners = _db.Owners.First()`. Later, when your program makes a call to `owners` accessing its `NavigationProperty` (like `owners.NavigationProperty.Name`), only then will a trip to the database be made to get the related `NavigationProperty` data.

Lazy-loading effectively does not load **navigation properties** until/if *they are required*. Good reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574232(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: Glad it was helpful.