# SQL Index on changed column

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, indexing

Is it possible to create an Index on column with changes of this column.
For example - I have a column A (nvarchar), But in query I should to replace values from this column to compare with values in list. Classical index will work only if I use original values from column A.

The query looks like next

```
SELECT
   * 
 FROM
    MyTable 
 WHERE
    REPLACE(A, ' ', '') IN ('aasa', 'asa', 'wew','wewe')
```

Comment: Using function in Where clause will avoid using `Index`. update your `A` column with `replace` function then replace function can be avoided in `where` clause.

Comment: @Prdp Yes, I know this way, but I need to store original values. At this moment I only see the way - to create new column B with replaced data and create index on this column. But there will be a lot of duplicated data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server - index on a computed column?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1323214/sql-server-index-on-a-computed-column)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a computed column and then create an index on it.

**Note:** SQL Server Index key columns have a [900 byte size limit](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191241(v=sql.105).aspx). Since your column is `NVARCHAR`, it consumes 2 bytes for each character. So, let's can cap the index at 400 characters (800 bytes).

To conserve space, we can further restrict this column to contain a value, only if it meets your required conditions.

```sql
ALTER TABLE MyTable
ADD A_NoSpace AS (CASE WHEN REPLACE(A, ' ', '') IN ('aasa', 'asa', 'wew','wewe') THEN LEFT(REPLACE(A, ' ', ''), 400) END) PERSISTED

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_A_NoSpace ON MyTable (A_NoSpace)
```

Being a [`PERSISTED`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186241.aspx) column, calculation will take place only during `INSERT` or `UPDATE` operations.

You can now use this column in your query:

```
SELECT *
FROM
MyTable
-- Don't need to check if value is in the list,
-- because we're already doing this in the computed column definition
WHERE A_NoSpace IS NOT NULL
```